# Orient animated camera horizon to object Y axis

Tags: animation, camera, animation-nodes, constraints

I have Empty in scene center and camera as a child to this empty.
Camera always look in center of scene and 2m far from this center.
In center i have long Y side object.

I "tilt" camera by adjusting Empty Y angle. And rotate around center of scene by rotating Z of empty.

Is this possible using constrains made camera horizontal (Y) orientation always horizontal to this long object?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

Locked Tracking to Empty moved along object Y angle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome, probably add note -to move empty along Y axis from centre (that took me a while to discover what caused the crazy shake) :)